# How to change password for SAMBA printer on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kde, samba, cups, kubuntu, printer

On my desktop at work with Kubuntu 14.04 I have (actually had) access to a network printer (Windows printer via SAMBA). After changing the password of my account I naturally have to reconfigure the printer with my new password, but...how do I do that?

I have looked at System Settings > Printer > Configure but I cannot seem to find anything useful there. Google is (apparently) not my friend on this matter.

Answer (score -2):

Try running `smbpasswd` logged in a yourself. It should prompt you for the old password and then for the new one.

The hash that SAMBA uses is stored separately from your Linux password and `smbpasswd` is the tool to change that. Some graphical tools to change your password might actually change both the Linux (`/etc/shadow`) password and the SAMBA password ( where that is actually stored depends on the back-end ) in one go.